# flash 8 datagrid sort arrow

Tags: flash

I am using an array to poulate a flash 8 datagrid, simple enough. I am also pre sorting the array by one of the fields, also simple enough.

I would like the sort arrow to be present when the grid is first populated, but it isn't!!

The user must click a header cell for the arrow to become visible. Is there any way to override this behaviour.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've touched as2. Apparently I couldn't get things to work without hacks.

Normally you should've be able to get away with dg.dispatchEvent({type:"headerRelease"}), but no, that didn't seem to work. I've used the Debug > List Objects option to get the name of a column header, then called the onRelease() function on it. Apparently that worked only in an onEnterFrame, which I later deleted.

Here's my code, built with help from the documentation:

```
//hacky boolean to check if what we asked for was done
var selfClicked:Boolean = false;

myDP = new Array({name:"Chris", price:"Priceless"},{name:"Daisy", price:"Adequate"}, {name:"Nigel", price:"Cheap"});
dg.dataProvider = myDP;

onEnterFrame = function(){
    if(!selfClicked){
        //ask nicely
        dg.dispatchEvent({type:"headerRelease"});
        //no ? oh well...
        dg.content_mc.header_mc.hO0.onRelease();
        //fix for header label
        dg.content_mc.header_mc.fHeaderCell0._y = dg.content_mc.header_mc.fHeaderCell1._y;
        selfClicked = true;
        delete onEnterFrame;
    }
}

this.headerRelease = function(eventObject){
    //nicely hidden debugging gem here, thanks Jen deHaan!
    trace(mx.data.binding.ObjectDumper.toString(eventObject));
}
dg.addEventListener("headerRelease", this);
```

HTH,
George

Comment: Hi George.

Thank you so much, that is awesome and does indeed force a placement of the arrow on the grid.

Couple of questions if I may.

What is the dispatch event line doing as it seems to work still when that is removed.

When I click on column 1 after the code has run, the header text moves differently to how it moves for the other columns ( abit ifficult to explain!).

Many thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi Dave. Usually you should be able to dispatch an event from the component and that should've fixed it. You can wipe that off, I that wanted to show the attempt to do it in a less hacky manner. I see what you mean, the header text move diagonally, not horizontally. I think that might be because the sort arrow clip isn't created until the header is pressed and since we're hacking it, the text is shifted a bit up (not sure why exactly), but you can fix that if you add the following line after th hO0.onRelease():
dg.content_mc.header_mc.fHeaderCell0._y = dg.content_mc.header_mc.fHeaderCell1._y;

Comment: Thanks George. I have found this works as well
dg.content_mc.header_mc.hO0.onPress(); dg.content_mc.header_mc.hO0.onRelease();It seems to do the full press and release and this fixes it. Nice! Thanks again

Comment: Yes, this has solved my problem nicely (as log as nothing unforeseen is happening under the hood!!) Many thanks

Comment: @eventdave You should accept some answers to encourage more people to contribute to your other questions.